# The type or name space "RestSharp" and "System" could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In the project.cs file the below code is added

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "RestSharp": "105.2.3"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
```

Below is the image that show the assemblies and reference is added to the reference folder.When I build the solution I am getting and error as "**The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System'**" and "**The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found**"

[image]

Below is the code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CommonModels;
using RestSharp;
using ServiceLayer.Interface;
using  System;



namespace ServiceLayer.ImplementaionClass
{
    public class WebApiCall<T> : IWebApiCall<T> where T : class 
    {
        private readonly string _baseUrl = string.Empty;
        public WebApiCall()
        {
            _baseUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"];
        }

    public GenericResponseObject<T> GetResponseObject(string actionurl,params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] namePairs)
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(actionurl, Method.GET);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> items in namePairs)
            {
                restRequest.AddParameter(items.Key, items.Value);
            }
            IRestResponse<GenericResponseObject<T>> response = restClient.Execute<GenericResponseObject<T>>(restRequest);
            GenericResponseObject<T> responseObject = response.Data;
            return responseObject;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `dotnet5.4`? I'm not sure that's been released yet.

Comment: The reference is added to .net 4.5.1 version as you can see in the project.json file the reference has not been added to .net 5.4 version. When I create a project with visual studio 2015 the structure is automatically added with project.json file as you can see in the image. Please help me to solve the error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been solve by deleting the below code from project.json file

```
"dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
```

Reference to the solution http://forums.asp.net/t/2060969.aspx?The+type+or+namespace+name+Configuration+does+not+exist+in+the+namespace+System+

Answer (score 0):

test your project properties, to see if you are using compact framework or not?
the problem seems to be of project configuration not the code itself.
change your target framework to see what happens.